# Rendering QImage on QGLWidget of QML plugin

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt4, qml

I'm trying to write a **QML plugin** that reads frames from a video (using a custom widget to do that task, NOT QtMultimedia/Phonon), and each frame is converted to a `QImage` RGB888, and then displayed on a `QGLWidget` (for performance reasons). Right now nothing is draw to the screen and the screen stays white all the time.

It's important to state that I already have all of this working without `QGLWidget`, so I know the issue is setting up and drawing on QGLWidget.

The plugin is being registered with:

```
qmlRegisterType&lt;Video&gt;(uri,1,0,"Video");
```

so `Video` is the main class of the plugin. On it's constructor we have:

```
Video::Video(QDeclarativeItem* parent)
: QDeclarativeItem(parent), d_ptr(new VideoPrivate(this))
{    
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemHasNoContents, false);            

    Q_D(Video);
    QDeclarativeView* view = new QDeclarativeView;
    view->setViewport(&d->canvas()); // canvas() returns a reference to my custom OpenGL Widget
}
```

Before I jump to the `canvas` object, let me say that I overloaded `Video::paint()` so it calls `canvas.paint()` while passing `QImage` as parameter, I don't know if this is the right way to do it so I would like some advice on this:

```
void Video::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(painter);
    Q_UNUSED(widget);
    Q_UNUSED(option);

    Q_D(Video);
    // I know for sure at this point "d->image()" is valid, but I'm hiding the code for clarity
    d->canvas().paint(painter, option, d->image());
}
```

The `canvas` object is declared as `GLWidget canvas;` and the header of this class is defined as:

```
class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:        
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget* parent = NULL);
    ~GLWidget();

    void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QImage* image);
};
```

Seems pretty simple. Now, the implementation of `QGLWidget` is the following:

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget* parent)
: QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers), parent)
{
   // Should I do something here?
   // Maybe setAutoFillBackground(false); ???
}

GLWidget::~GLWidget()
{
}
```

And finally:

```
void GLWidget::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QImage* image)
{
   // I ignore painter because it comes from Video, so I create a new one:
   QPainter gl_painter(this);


   // Perform drawing as Qt::KeepAspectRatio

   gl_painter.fillRect(QRectF(QPoint(0, 0), QSize(this->width(), this->height())), Qt::black);

   QImage scaled_img = image->scaled(QSize(this->width(), this->height()), _ar, Qt::FastTransformation);

   gl_painter.drawImage(qRound(this->width()/2)  - qRound(scaled_img.size().width()/2),
                        qRound(this->height()/2) - qRound(scaled_img.size().height()/2),
                        scaled_img); 
}
```

What am I missing?

I originally asked [this question on Qt Forum](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/12358/) but got no replies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solved**. The problem was that I was trying to create a new GL context within my plugin when I should be retrieving the GL context from the application that loaded it.

**[This code](https://gitorious.org/peregrine/peregrine/blobs/master/qml-plugin/videooutput/qmlvideo.cpp) was very helpful** to understand how to accomplish that.

By the way, I discovered that the stuff was being draw inside `view`. It's just that I needed to execute `view->show()`, but that created another window which was not what I was looking for. The link I shared above has the answer.

Comment: Do you still have the source? I am currently facing a similar problem and the link goes to 404.

Comment: I will try to paste it here when i can.

Comment: [Here it is](https://gitorious.org/peregrine/peregrine/blobs/master/qml-plugin/videooutput/qmlvideo.cpp)

Comment: Dead link. New one too that is.

Comment: This thread has almost 9 years of age. The repository where the reference code was originally published DIED and is long gone. This is the last time I'll track down a similar source code on the Internet for reference. [Here it is](https://github.com/longwei/qmlvideo/blob/study2/qmlvideo.cpp). Good luck from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to draw on your glwidget using the opengl functions.

One possible way is to override your paintGL() method in GLWidget
and then draw your image with glDrawPixels().

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glDrawPixels(buffer.width(), buffer.height(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer.bits());
```

Where buffer is a QImage object that needs to be converted using QGLWidget::converrtToGLFormat() static method.

Look at this source for reference:
https://github.com/nayyden/ZVector/blob/master/src/GLDebugBufferWidget.cpp

Comment: For some reason, `GLWidget::paintGL()` is not being called, even if I change on `Video::paint()` for it to execute `d->canvas().update(); d->canvas().repaint();`

Comment: One stupid suggestion I might give is to add a new public method to your GLWidget and in that method call paintGL() and updateGL() but then you will have to type cast the canvas when you want to call it.

Comment: I really don't want to use OpenGL calls directly, that's why I'm not overloading GL methods like `paintGL()`.

Comment: If you are still interested, this problem has been solved. You can check my answer if you would like.